# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load config data from

Tags: spring-boot

I am getting the following error when I try to deploy a war file on a non-production environment. For some reason, I have externalized the property file. What mistake I might be doing?

*Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load config data from 'file:E:\ApplicationServer\apache-tomcat-9.0.21\webapps\config\'*

Comment: does the war contain the file?

Comment: Yes property file is there in the war also